# How does Django deployments happen on Servers?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, release

I learnt how to deploy the django projects to EC2 instances.

Basically 1st time when the django project is deployed to EC2, the instance will be configured with httpd.conf, wsgi, change permissions on files and folders and other stuff and the project will be cloned to the EC2 instance and server is restarted.

My question is how do they do future deployments? They in this context is anyone who deploys Django on EC2 instances.

Do they login to EC2 instances and manually clone the repository from VCS site and restart the server?

Do they have any other automated mechanism to pull the code, ensure permissions and restarting the apache server etc.

How is it done basically every time they go for a release?

Comment: There are many, many ways to get a django project onto an (EC2) server. You should do some more research into them & see what works for you. If you have a specific problem with getting a server running you may find answers here; https://serverfault.com/

Comment: A good starting point would be to look at elastic beanstalk for deployment